# Android smali mod: replace intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, smali

I'm trying to modify an existing App.  Currently this is one action of this App which when chosen will bring out the Wireless & Network setting page.  I used `APKTOOL` to get the `smali` and located the code:

```
.line 238
new-instance p5, Landroid/content/Intent;

const-string p7, "android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"

.end local p7
invoke-direct {p5, p7}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

I'm trying to make it instead of calling the setting page it would call my own app.  Unfortunately I couldn't disassemble the whole class, but I got the following

```
var10_10.bitmap = WidgetItem.loadFunctionIcon((Context)var1_1, (String)var8_8, (boolean)var6_6, (boolean)var7_7);
var10_10.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity((Context)var1_1, (int)0, (Intent)new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"), (int)134217728);
var11_11 = true;
```

I tried to replace the smali code from

```
const-string p7, "android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"
```

to

```
const-string p7, "com.mycompany.myapp"
```

or

```
const-string p7, "com.mycompany.myapp@com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity"
```

but both did not work.  What should I put there for it to call my app?

Comment: whatever the string u put, have u tried to have an intent filter/receiver for that action? never mind the package, just put there "tweedledeedle" and listen for that

Comment: thanks for your hint.  now i look at the other part of the code and found:         
            var26_23 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            var26_23.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
            var26_23.setFlags(270532608);
            var26_23.setComponent(new ComponentName(var8_8, var9_9));
        } else {
            var26_23 = var0.getLaunchIntentForPackage(var8_8);
        }
        var10_10.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity((Context)var1_1, (int)0, (Intent)var26_23, (int)134217728);  i think i need to replicate this....

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the following, it works!

From

```
var10_10.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity((Context)var1_1, (int)0, (Intent)new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"), (int)134217728);
```

To

```
var53_15 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
var53_15.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
var53_15.setFlags(270532608);
var8_8 = "com.mycompany.myapp";
var9_9 = "com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity";
var53_15.setComponent(new ComponentName(var8_8, var9_9));
var10_10.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity((Context)var1_1, (int)0, (Intent)var53_15, (int)134217728);
```